# Can I create custom buttons for YouTube and Facebook and implement redirects to connect my application?

Tags: facebook, youtube, youtube-api, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I'm developing a web application and I'm connecting it to YouTube and Facebook using custom buttons. I've added a redirect to facilitate the connection with my application.

I found on Facebook's documentation that it's possible to create a manual login flow using redirects. I found it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/. Following a similar approach, I perform a redirect to the URL: [https://www.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={APP_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={APP_REDIRECT_URL}&scopes={APP_SCOPES}](https://www.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7BAPP_CLIENT_ID%7D&redirect_uri=%7BAPP_REDIRECT_URL%7D&scopes=%7BAPP_SCOPES%7D), and this implementation has been working perfectly for me. However, I'm concerned whether Facebook accepts this method or if I need to use the official Facebook SDK.

Additionally, I want to point out that for both Facebook and YouTube, I've created very simple custom buttons. The Facebook connect button only displays the text "Connect to Facebook," with no associated image, and I'm trying to match it with Facebook's brand colors. Similarly, for YouTube, the button has the text "Connect to YouTube," and I'm aiming to use YouTube's brand colors as well. Both buttons use redirects to carry out the connection.

My question is: Is it acceptable for Facebook and YouTube to allow this implementation with redirects while customizing the button styles to match their respective brand colors, or is it mandatory to use the official Facebook SDK and some method provided by Google for YouTube?

I appreciate any guidance or recommendations to ensure that I'm following best practices regarding the connection of my application with these platforms.

Thank you!

I've been using custom buttons and redirections to complete the connection between youtube/facebook and my application

Comment: No, it is not mandatory to use any SDK.

Comment: Facebook has some guidelines regarding login button styling, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience#buttondesign Google/YouTube might have something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for sharing the link to Facebook's guidelines regarding login button styling.